# Stacking labels in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, roc, ggrepel

I am building empirical ROC curves and am stuck with a few that do not look very sensible. I am using `geom_text_repel` but they are simply to close to each other. I was wondering if someone can offer some sensible solution.

The data:

```
    structure(list(sens = c(0, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 
0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.7, 0.7, 1), one_min_spec = c(0, 
0, 0, 0.021, 0.021, 0.021, 0.041, 0.041, 0.041, 0.041, 0.041, 
0.041, 0.041, 0.041, 0.062, 0.062, 0.108, 0.17, 0.183, 1), cut_point = c(NA, 
18L, 17L, 16L, 15L, 14L, 13L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 
5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, NA)), row.names = c(1L, 12156L, 11470L, 10784L, 
10098L, 9412L, 8726L, 8040L, 7354L, 6668L, 5982L, 5296L, 4610L, 
3924L, 3238L, 2552L, 1866L, 1180L, 494L, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

And the plotting code:

```
ggplot(df, aes(one_min_spec, sens, label = cut_point)) +
  geom_abline(
    intercept = 0,
    slope = 1,
    color = "black",
    linetype = "dashed"
  ) +
  geom_path(colour = "gray") +
  geom_point(colour = "black") +
  geom_text_repel(size = 4) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1),
                     expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 1),
                     expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 14))
```

I was thinking maybe to try to create a single label for each point, instead of a number of them if they are sharing the same point in ROC space. I.e. in this case it would be a single label 6-13 instead all cut points having one. Not really sure how to do it and does it make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to condense the cutpoints to a single label, here's one way to do it:

```
library(dplyr)

df2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(one_min_spec, sens) %>% 
  summarise(cut_point = ifelse(all(is.na(cut_point)),
                               "",
                               range(cut_point, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
                                 unique() %>%
                                 paste(collapse = "-"))) %>%
  ungroup()

> df2
# A tibble: 9 x 3
  one_min_spec  sens cut_point
         <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    
1        0       0   ""       
2        0       0.2 17-18    
3        0.021   0.4 14-16    
4        0.041   0.4 6-13     
5        0.062   0.5 4-5      
6        0.108   0.5 3        
7        0.17    0.7 2        
8        0.183   0.7 1        
9        1       1   ""
```

This processed data frame will work with your original `ggplot()` code. I've simplified it somewhat below for illustration:

```
ggplot(df2, aes(one_min_spec, sens, label = cut_point)) +
  geom_abline(linetype = "dashed") + # the rest are the same as default options anyway
  geom_path(colour = "gray") +
  geom_point(colour = "black") +
  geom_text_repel(size = 4)
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I meant, but it would take me like 50 lines of code, neat solution. Do we need `all`?

Comment: `all()` is there in case there are multiple cut point values at the same `one_min_spec` / `sens` combination, & they are all NAs. If that scenario is impossible, feel free to remove it. :)

Comment: ah right, it is in my case but someone might re-use it later. I  just added NAs at the beginning and the end for plotting and AUC calc (this is veery empirical ROC).